# How do you navigate documentation in Emacs?

Tags: help, documentation, info

There is some manual I have accessed before on Emacs that described how to navigate the documentation and also how it was constructed. However, I have forgotten how to get there.

From memory, the documentation outlines:

- What 'Top', 'Next', 'Previous' mean and how to action them
- What nodes and sub-nodes are
- How using `<SPC>` will ensure you don't skip sub-nodes

Would anybody know how to get there again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing <kbd>h</kbd> while browsing `info` brings up the relevant manual.

Comment: Thank you so much @DoMiNeLa10! I never would have figured that out again without trawling through the history of documents I read a few days ago.

Comment: Also type `d` at any time in the info reader to jump to the main directory node, which provides this and other helpful tips at the top.